# Force fantasy lineup to chose players from a specific number of teams?

Tags: r, constraints, mathematical-optimization

Given the following fantasy hockey model in R using RGLPK how do I  force a selection from a total of 4 teams? My model is

```
num.players <- length(players[,1])
f <- players$proj
var.types <- rep("B", num.players)
A <- rbind(
as.numeric(players$position == "W"),as.numeric(players$position == "W"),
as.numeric(players$position == "C"),as.numeric(players$position == "C"),
as.numeric(players$position == "D"),as.numeric(players$position == "D"),
as.numeric(players$position == "G"),
as.numeric(players$position %in% c("W","C","D","G")),
players$salary)
dir <- c(
">=","<=",
">=","<=",
">=","<=",
"==",
"==",
"<=")
b <- c(
3,4,
2,3,
2,3,
1,
9,
50000)
sol <- Rglpk_solve_LP(obj = f, mat = A, dir = dir, rhs = b,                      types = var.types, max = TRUE)
```

I attempted to add the following constraint

```
length(unique(players$team)),
"==",
4,
```

This constraint was always true since my data has 14 teams and the length(unique(players$team)) was using the entire dataset not just the selected players.